# in vs. on for Earth and code

Tags: articles

I have three phrases in Spanish I would like to translate to English:

- Simon en Japón.
- Simon en la Tierra.
- Simon en el código.

I think these would be the proper translations:

- Simon in Japan.
- Simon in the Earth.
- Simon in the code.

The meaning I want to transmit is that of Simon being physically in that place. Simon is in Japan, Simon is in the (planet) Earth, Simon is in the (computer source) code.

I've read a lot about "in" vs. "on", and wether to use "the" before "Earth". I believe these translations are appropriate, but I would like to check with native speakers.

UPDATE:

There is no verb in the phrases because they will be used as titles.

From your answers the first two phrases would become:

- Simon in Japan
- Simon on Earth

Regarding the last one, the intent is metaphorical.

- Simon in Japan: Simon went to Japan, explored and had adventures.
- Simon on Earth: Simon went to other places on Earth, explored and had adventures.
- Simon in/on the code: (metaphorically) Simon goes into the source code, explores and has adventures.

In the last case, would it be better "on"?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "in the code". Japan is a place, but computer source code is not a place where a person can be. Do you mean that Simon is reading or editing the code? Or do you mean that is Simon not a person in this example but rather something related to the text of the code (e.g., "There are several errors in the code" or "There are security rules in the code to protect my website")?

Comment: Software developers routinely say "Simon is in the code" meaning "he is studying the code" or "he is making changes to the code". Like, "Boss: We've got a complaint that our order system is not charging the correct sales tax. Employee: Yes, Bob is in the code now trying to find the problem." Whether this is what the OP meant I can't say.

Comment: @Jay - I'm not sure what the last one means, either, but my first thought was that "Simon" was no longer a person, but a computer virus or algorithm. _How can I use Simon? I never bought Simon._ Answer: _Don't worry about it; Simon is in the code_. (In that case, "in the code" means "embedded in the code".) But your interpretation is viable, too; we need to O.P. to clarify.

Comment: @J.R. true...Simon seems to be a third gen worm/virus! :)

Comment: Re: the code, the intent is metaphorical. Simon is exploring the code, as if it was a place. Would "in" be appropriate in this context?

Comment: @Simon - In that case, we might say "Simon is lost _in_ thought," but we generally say, "Simon is really _into_ the code."

Comment: @simon Among developers: Yes, we often say "Simon is in the code" to mean he is studying it or modifying it. See my previous comment.

Comment: @J.R. For most subjects that one could get interested in, we do indeed say "into": "Simon is really into Tolkien", etc. But the idiom in software development circles is that we say "Simon is in the code", not "into the code". That's just how the jargon has shaken out. If you want to say that Simon likes a particular software tool or language, then we're back to the conventional idiom: "Simon used to like Visual Basic but he's into Java now", etc.

Comment: @Jay - Perhaps that's true, but, in that case, I think "Simon is looking at the code" or "Simon is modifying the code" might be a better way to say it.

Comment: @J.R. Sure, that would be more clear and precise. But every profession and cultural group has its own little dialect, and the fact that you or I think a phrase is ambiguous or otherwise undesirable isn't likely to change the usage. Like, I think the way astronomers refer to stars, planets, meteoroids, etc collectively as "objects" is a very bland and vague terminology. But I can't imagine they'll change that usage because I said so.

Comment: @Jay - Odd. I was a software engineer for about 10 years, and I don't recall hearing that. "Jane is coding," perhaps, or, "Jane is working on the code," or maybe even, "Jane is buried in the code," but not, "Jane is in the code." (BTW, I'm not arguing the point – I'm just surprised it sounds unfamiliar to me.)

Comment: @J.R. Perhaps it's a regionalism. Where did you live? I've heard that idiom in Ohio and Michigan, U.S.A. Now I'd have to think back if I've seen it in print, on the Internet, etc, where it might come from other places.

Comment: @Jay - It could be a regionalism, or it could be corporate slang, where some companies use it, and others don't. Thanks for your comments, though. _Learn something new every day_...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Simon is **in** the Earth.

This sentence would mean "Simon is **inside** the Earth", he is somewhere underground, under the surface.

> Simon is **on** the Earth.

This sentence would mean "Simon is on the surface of the planet Earth".

Your other two translations are fine, just don't forget to use **is**. Omitting **is** makes a sentence like "Simon in the code" suitable for a headline or turns it into a phrase that cannot stand on its own and should be included into some sentence.

Comment: I plan to use it as headlines. I'll use "Simon in Japan", "Simon on Earth" and "Simon in the code". Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

> Simon en Japón.

Here *Simon in Japan* is OK. This might vary a bit based on context.

> Simon en la Tierra.

would be:

> Simon is **on** the land.

Since *Tierra* is capitalized, I suppose this is referring to a specific location such as a country, park, etc.
If you say *Simon is in the land*, it would be like he was underground.

> Simon en el código.

Based on you description (and in the comments), I think you are trying to say:

> Simon is **into** the code.

Here *into* refers to a strong interest. Refer to [***into***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/into) sense 7:

> 7) (US, informal) involved in, interested in, or concerned with

(Non-Spanish speaking disclaimer. It has been a long time since high school.)